# Angular/Typescrit object modified in read-only loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am experiencing some trouble when searching an array of objects for a object with a given property. The data source is originally a REST-API, but since data changes only from time to time it is saved in an object, which is used for the further requests in the application.
Here is the code that causes the trouble:

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private poolService: PoolDTOServiceService) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => this.getPool(params));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getPool(params: Params) {
    console.log('called method');
    for (let i = 0; i < this.poolService.jsonResponse.pools.length; i++) {
      const pool = this.poolService.jsonResponse.pools[i];
      for (let o = 0; o < pool.membersReference.items.length; o++) {
        const member = pool.membersReference.items[o];
        if (member.name === params['name']) {
          console.log('called if');
          console.log(member);
          this.pool = member;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here are the objects that are accessed within the loop (jsonResponse is just the dummy object that contains the list of pools):

Here is the `PoolDTO` (accessed by `pools[i]`). It is a simple DTO:

```
  private _kind: String;
  private _name: String;
  private _partition: String;
  private _fullPath: String;
  private _generation: String;
  private _selfLink: String;
  private _allowNat: String;
  private _allowSnat: String;
  private _description: String;
  private _ignorePersistanceWeight: String;
  private _ipTosToClient: String;
  private _ipTosToServer: String;
  private _linkQosToClient: String;
  private _LinkQosToServer: String;
  private _loadBalancingMode: String;
  private _minActiveMembers: String;
  private _minUpMembers: String;
  private _minUpMembersAction: String;
  private _minUpMembersChecking: String;
  private _monitor: String;
  private _queueDepthLimit: String;
  private _queueOnConnectionLimit: String;
  private _queueTimeLimit: String;
  private _reselectTries: String;
  private _serviceDownAction: String;
  private _slowRampTime: String;
  private _membersReference: MembersReferenceDTO;
```

The `membersReference` holds an array called items, which contains `PoolMemberDTO`s:

```
  private _dynamicRatio: String;
  private _ephermal: String;
  private _inheritProfile: String;
  private _logging: String;
  private _priorityGroup: String;
  private _rateLimit: String;
  private _ratio: String;
  private _state: String;
  private _address: String;
  private _subItems: any[];
  private _name: String;
```

Here is the `poolService`:

```
private _jsonResponse: JsonResponseDTO;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getPools().subscribe((p) => {
      this._jsonResponse = p;
    });
  }

  public getPools(): Observable<JsonResponseDTO> {
    return this.http.get<JsonResponseDTO>('http://localhost:8080/pools');
  }

  public getPoolArray(): PoolDTO[] {
    return this._jsonResponse.pools;
  }

  public setJsonResponse() {
    this.http.get<JsonResponseDTO>('http://localhost:8080/pools').subscribe((next) => {this._jsonResponse = next; });
  }


  get jsonResponse(): JsonResponseDTO {
    return this._jsonResponse;
  }
```

The `setJsonResponse` method only exists to get the new data from time to time.

Now the description of the problem: The component that causes trouble is 'created' by a child route, giving the name property. This one is used to find a specific pool member of a pool. I logged the member and what happened:
There are two logs generated:
The first one is the correct one, the second one contains a different `ratio` value. The other properties are equal.

**What I have done so far**
I switched between `forEach()` and traditional `for`-loops, using even `return` / `break` in the if-condition to leave the loop and get the 'first'. That did not work too.

**What I checked**
I checked in my Unit-tests in my backend that there are no dupilcate servers. The name property is used for the comparison, so a behaviour as experienced here should not be possible.

I logged the `jsonResponse` object after it is received from the backend and checked, that the corresponding pool is correct in there. It is correct.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: You are leaving out the most important part: **how/when** is the child component created from the `_name` property?

Comment: problem is solved, I had an issue witht the identifier that is used to identify a specific pool member, but this problem was caused by an external REST-API